# Tcc Antivirus impedir de Finalizar processo delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe3

Estou concluindo um projeto, criando um aplicativo que simule um antivírus.

A aplicação é em Delphi, o que eu quero saber é como os antivírus fazem para registrar um processo como usuário system, e quando você clica em finalizar o processo aparece , 'Acesso Negado!'.

Abaixo achei uma luz só que registra o processo no sistema, mas, sem sucesso.

```
Function RegisterServiceProcess(DwProcessID, dwType: DWord): DWord; StdCall; External 'KERNEL32.dll';
//Para chamar
RegisterServiceProcess(GetCurrentProcessID, 1);
```

Alguma luz?

Comment: Boa Noite, talvez este post lê ajude... [http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=62164&sid=9c81985c50d8cd96b914bdc6f263d66f](http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=62164&sid=9c81985c50d8cd96b914bdc6f263d66f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Create do Formulário adicione a chamada para essa função:

```
function PreventProcessKill: Integer;
var
  hProcess:Thandle;
  EmptyDacl: TACL ;
  pEmptyDacl: PACL ;
  dwErr : DWORD ;
begin
  hProcess := GetCurrentProcess();
  ZeroMemory(@EmptyDacl, SizeOF(tacl));
  pEmptyDacl := @EmptyDacl;

  if (not InitializeAcl(EmptyDacl, sizeof(tACL), 2)) then
    dwErr := GetLastError()
  else  
    dwErr := SetSecurityInfo(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, GetCurrentProcessID),
             SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, @ACL, nil);
  Result:= dwErr;
end;
```

Você precisa declarar nas `uses`: *AclAPI* e *AccCtrl*.

> Nota: AccCtrl é uma Dll, geralmente não encontrada em todas as versões
>   do Windows

Comment: otima dica, porem meu projeto esta ocorrendo um erro ao iniciar, ele nao esta conseguindo interpretar o @ACL na parte do else. Testei e se eu colocar nil ele roda normalmente, sabe me dizer o que possa ser?

Comment: Essa função inicia meu processo como usuário system? tentei compilar e como você informou ocorreu um erro relacionado a AccCtrl, exatamente nessa linha SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, @ACL, nil); , qual seria a solução .

Comment: Um processo iniciado como system não garante que ele não poderá ser finalizado! Essa função aumenta o nível de segurança do seu processo, afim de não ser possível finalizar por outros meios, sobre o erro é como eu disse, você precisa da DLL, terá que expandir sua pesquisa!